# OpenRealm ROS1 Bridge problems

Tags: c++, cmake, pthreads, ros

I have some problem following this installation guide https://github.com/laxnpander/OpenREALM_ROS1_Bridge
Before **quick start** section, the command *catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release* does not work.

It is the last step before to use the whole library.

Someone can help me?

Example of the errors:

```
CMake Error at OpenREALM_ROS1_Bridge/realm_ros/CMakeLists.txt:141 (add_executable):
  Target "realm_exiv2_grabber" links to target "Boost::filesystem" but the
  target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at OpenREALM_ROS1_Bridge/realm_ros/CMakeLists.txt:141 (add_executable):
  Target "realm_exiv2_grabber" links to target "FLANN::FLANN" but the target
  was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at OpenREALM_ROS1_Bridge/realm_ros/CMakeLists.txt:137 (add_executable):
  Target "realm_ros_grabber" links to target "Boost::filesystem" but the
  target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at OpenREALM_ROS1_Bridge/realm_ros/CMakeLists.txt:137 (add_executable):
  Target "realm_ros_grabber" links to target "FLANN::FLANN" but the target
  was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at OpenREALM_ROS1_Bridge/realm_ros/CMakeLists.txt:109 (add_library):
  Target "realm_ros" links to target "Boost::filesystem" but the target was
  not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at OpenREALM_ROS1_Bridge/realm_ros/CMakeLists.txt:109 (add_library):
  Target "realm_ros" links to target "FLANN::FLANN" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at OpenREALM_ROS1_Bridge/realm_ros/CMakeLists.txt:145 (add_executable):
  Target "realm_stage_node" links to target "Boost::filesystem" but the
  target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at OpenREALM_ROS1_Bridge/realm_ros/CMakeLists.txt:145 (add_executable):
  Target "realm_stage_node" links to target "FLANN::FLANN" but the target was
  not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


-- Generating done
CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
```

I don't have any idea of how to solve it.

Cheers!

Comment: @Tsyvarev I already post an example of CMakeError's file. If I open the file I see the examples that I post repetead many times

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the correct boost libraries are actually added to the `CMakeLists.txt`. That repo does not appear to be set up correctly. In `realm_ros/CMakeLists.txt` find the line `target_link_libraries(...)` and add:

```
${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARIES}
${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I found these lines: 
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
        ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
        ${cmake_modules_LIBRARIES}
        ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}
 realm_stages
)

target_link_libraries(realm_ros_grabber PUBLIC ${PROJECT_NAME})
target_link_libraries(realm_exiv2_grabber PUBLIC ${PROJECT_NAME})
target_link_libraries(realm_stage_node PUBLIC ${PROJECT_NAME})
I tried to insert your advice after $(PROJECT_NAME) in the last 3 lines, and after ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES} but before "realm_stages" for the first found line. The result is same as before :(

Comment: @MatrixUnibo do you have `boost` and `FLANN` installed?

Comment: this is the link to the CMakeLists file https://github.com/laxnpander/OpenREALM_ROS1_Bridge/blob/master/realm_ros/CMakeLists.txt

Comment: I already install libflann-dev,libboost-dev and libboost-all-dev on my Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: The above CMake file is the one I was refereeing to with missing link libraries. Looking through the repo, it's setup for Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04. Trying to run it on 20.04 and Noetic is probably causing your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I read that OpenRealm is for ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS but it is not true for the "Bridge". OK, right now, I have to downgrade my ubuntu system and try the installation from the begginning... I will let you know